# Run-Time error '-2147024703 (800700c1)' when running Access 2010 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, 64-bit, ms-access-2010

I have an application written in MS ACCESS 2007 using VBA, connecting to an SQL Server at the back end. Both Access and SQL Server are running locally.
My machine runs Access 2010 and MS SQL Server Express 2008 R2 (both 32-bit, on WinXP) with no problem.

I have another machine, Win7 64-bit, running both Access 2010 and SQL Server 2008 (NOT R2) 64-bit.

When I run the Access application on the 64-bit machine, I have a drop down box to select the SQL Server which holds the various databases. When I select the server, after a few seconds I get an error:

> Run-time error '-2147024703 (800700c1)':
>
> Automation error %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

When I select the Debug option, the yellow arrow points to:
`Set oServer = New SQLDMO.SQLServer`

The next line is:
`oServer.Connect ServerName, strSQLUser, strSQLPwd`

In the watch list, I can see that `ServerName`, `strSQLUser`, and strSQLPwd hold the right values to access the SQL Server. I've tested these in sqlcmd and successfully was able to query tables.

Can anyone please help me out on this one? I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've got registered a 32-bit SQLDMO on your system that is being used for connection to the 64-bit instance. Check your registry / file system for SQLDMO.dll versions and register the correct one.

Also check MSDN "[Installing SQL-DMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141187%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)" because SQLDMO was scheduled for remove after SQL Server 2008 R2:

> Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.
>
> SQL Server Database Management Objects (SQL-DMO) has been removed from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and the SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack. SQL-DMO also does not support Database Engine features introduced after SQL Server 2000. We recommend that you modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. If you must support SQL-DMO, install the Backward Compatibility Components from the SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack from the Microsoft Download Center. Do not use SQL-DMO in new development work; use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) instead. You can obtain the SMO documentation by installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this.

I looked to find SQLDMO.DLL 64-bit version, but although using the Backwards Comparability package for x64, installing using the MSI did not do the job.

I had to manually extract the files and place the correct version (which is ~2MB larger than the x86 version as an indication to knowing which one is the x64) and then run 'regsvr32 sqldmo.dll ' in the command line (very important: need to run cmd as Administrator for this to succeed).

After the module has been registered, my Access front end run great.